# Will warning "Potential loss of keychain access" automatically go away in the next update I push to app store?

Tags: ios, app-store

I am receiving the following warning email from the itunes

> Potential Loss of Keychain Access - The previous version of software has an application-identifier value of ['****.****.****.****'] and the new version of software being submitted has an application-identifier of ['####.****.****.****']. This will result in a loss of keychain access.

If I choose to ignore the warning (As I don't need keychain access, Handoff, and UIPasteboard sharing) and release it to the app store when I update a new version of the app next time will this warning still show up?

Comment: @iYoung Thanks. I have actually already seen that. And I understand that I can ignore the warning because I don't use "keychain access, Handoff, and UIPasteboard sharing". My question is if I choose to ignore it in this release will this warning still show up when I update again?

Comment: No it won't show @MahbubMorshedProttoy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We also had the same issue. but it won't affect your app. This problem arrises due to mismatch of CSR file while u create the account. if we use different CSR file we will get this issue. but the app store ipa will upload in app store. this is just a warning.

when you update the app for the second time using the same CSR file you created you wont receive this warning email.

Answer (score 0):

Have to changed your app Id? Or transferred your App? Anything that will lead to change in Singing entitlements.

Here what apple says about keychain access

> Every keychain item in iOS contains an attribute called the keychain
>   access group. An iOS app can only access those keychain items it has
>   permission to. This permission comes from the code signing
>   entitlements stamped into the app when it is signed (using your
>   current App ID prefix)

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2311/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40014135-CH1-A_ONE_TIME_LOSS_IN_KEYCHAIN_DATA_WILL_OCCUR_IF_YOU_SWITCH_YOUR_APP_ID_PREFIX

This warning will not unless code signing entitlements are changed.